# Can a class have an abstract class as attribute in Java?

Tags: java, abstract

I have an abstract class `Product`

```
public abstract class Product implements Serializable {
   private Integer id;
   private LocalDateTime creationDate;
   private LocalDateTime updateDate;
   //constructors etc..
}
```

then I have multiple child classes that extend `Product` and an `Ad` class which lists the products. My question is: can I use the `Product` class as an attribute? so it could be instantiated with the different child classes like this:

```
public class Ad implements Serializable {
   private Integer id;
   private Product product;
   //constructors and methods..
}


Ad example = new Ad(1,childClass);
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.  Do you intend `childClass` to be an object of some subclass of `Product`, or do you intend it to be the actual class, which your constructor would then have to instantiate?

Comment: the main pourpuse its to have a single table of ads but been able to list multiple type of products, lets say "cars" or "boats", Im not sure if thats posible.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is whether you can use the `Product` class which is the abstract class as an attribute so it could be initiated with the different child class implementation of it ? Answer is yes!

I will add a simple example below:

***Abstract class***

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {

  abstract void test();

}
```

***Child class***

```
public class ChildClass extends AbstractClass {

  @Override
  void test() {

  }

}
```

***Example usage***

```
public class Example {

  private static AbstractClass abstractClass;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    abstractClass = new ChildClass();
  }

}
```

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

## Yes, member field can be an abstract type

Yes, a member field may be of a type that is abstract.

Of course you will need to use a concrete implementation of that abstract class to instantiate an object to populate that field.

### Alternate example

Here is a different example, to be a bit more concrete (pardon the pun). We have an unrealistic portrayal of a veterinary clinic with animal patient visits.

In this example, we show an abstract class (`Pet`) as a member field (on `Visit`), with either of two concrete classes (`Cat`, `Dog`) used to populate that field.

A `Visit` is a [record](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) consisting of a date and a `Pet` object.

```
record Visit( LocalDate date , Pet pet ) { }
```

The `Pet` class is abstract. This abstract class defines a read-only property of `name`, for the name of each patient animal.

```
abstract class Pet { … }
```

So we have concrete classes `Cat` & `Dog` which extend `Pet`. These concrete classes inherit the `name` property from their abstract superclass.

```
class Cat extends Pet { … }
class Dog extends Pet { … }
```

We declare the `Visit` member field to be of type `Pet` while we populate with concrete classes for cats and dogs.

```
new Visit( LocalDate.of( 2022 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) , fluffy )   // Cat
…
new Visit( LocalDate.of( 2022 , Month.MARCH , 23 ) , rover )  // Dog
```

Notice how I used `this.getClass().getSimpleName()` in the `toString` override on `Pet`. This shows the magic of [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)), and verifies how we have objects of a **concrete class being held in a member field of an abstract type**.

For the example data, we have Fluffy the cat visiting on January 23, with a follow-up visit a month later on February 28. In another month, we have Rover the dog visiting on March 7.

```java
package work.basil.example.vet;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.util.List;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        Cat fluffy = new Cat( "Fluffy" );
        Dog rover = new Dog( "Rover" );

        List < Visit > visits =
                List.of(
                        new Visit( LocalDate.of( 2022 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) , fluffy ) ,
                        new Visit( LocalDate.of( 2022 , Month.FEBRUARY , 28 ) , fluffy ) ,
                        new Visit( LocalDate.of( 2022 , Month.MARCH , 7 ) , rover )
                );

        System.out.println( "visits = " + visits );
    }

    abstract class Pet
    {
        private String name;

        String getName ( ) /* Getter */ { return this.name; }

        public Pet ( String name )  /* Constructor */ { this.name = name; }

        @Override
        public String toString ( )
        {
            return "Pet{ " +
                    "class=" + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " | " +
                    "name=" + name +
                    " }";
        }
    }

    class Cat extends Pet
    {
        public Cat ( String name )  /* Constructor */ { super( name ); }
    }

    class Dog extends Pet
    {
        public Dog ( String name )  /* Constructor */ { super( name ); }
    }

    record Visit( LocalDate date , Pet pet ) { }
}
```

> visits = [Visit[date=2022-01-23, pet=Pet{ class=Cat | name=Fluffy }], Visit[date=2022-02-28, pet=Pet{ class=Cat | name=Fluffy }], Visit[date=2022-03-07, pet=Pet{ class=Dog | name=Rover }]]